# «На яхте будеЕТ три мачты» или «будУТ три мачты»?

Tags: грамотная-речь, орфография, грамматика, согласование, единственное-множественное-число

Прошу помочь: какая форма правильная и почему?

1. На яхте будет три мачты, изготовленные из углеродного волокна?
2. На яхте будут три мачты, изготовленные из углеродного волокна?

Answer (score 3):

[Розенталь Д.Э.](http://evartist.narod.ru/text1/64.htm#%D0%B7_02)   При числительных два, ***три***, четыре, двое, трое, четверо ***сказуемое обычно ставится в форме множественного числа***, например: *Два солдата с котомками равнодушно глядели на окна поезда... (А.Н. Толстой)*. ***Но сказуемые-глаголы со значением бытия, наличия, существования, положения в пространстве и т.д. (т.е. со значением состояния, а не действия) обычно в этих случаях употребляются в форме единственного числа***, например: *... У него *было* два сына (Чехов); В комнате ***было*** два окна с широкими подоконниками (Каверин)...*.

Итак, число сказуемого ***будет*** должно быть единственное. *Три мачты* - цельное словосочетание. Обособленное определение, относящееся к цельному словосочетанию-подлежащему, тоже употребляем в И.п.Три мачты (они) и изготовленные (они) согласуются и во множ.числе. Получаем ответ:

***На яхте будет три мачты, изготовленные из углеродного волокна.***

Answer (score 2):

Правильный вариант "На яхте будет три мачты, изготовленные из углеродного волокна."

Answer (score 2):

Согласна, в данном контексте верно употребление единственного числа сказуемого:"На яхте будет три мачты, изготовленные из углеродного волокна."

Почему? Потому что в этом сообщении главное, что их три, это бросается в глаза, отличает от других яхт, а то, что они изготовлены из углеродного волокна, -уже для специалистов, подробности не для всех.

Вот если бы было "Три мачты буд**у**т изготовлены из углеродного волокна." Здесь деятель - три мачты.Важно не число, а то, из чего изготовлены.

Comment: Или так: "На яхте будут установлены три мачты". Есть ощущение, что автор был ограничен числом знаков, и это есть причина трудностей.

Answer (score 2):

Мне нравится такой вариант:

На яхте будет три мачты, изготовленных из углеродного волокна.

ПОЯСНЕНИЕ

1) Ед. число связано с препозицией сказуемого и неодушевленностью подлежащего.

2)  Но форма "изготовленные", как отметил Slava, поддерживается мн. числом и конфликтует с ед. числом  сказуемого, поэтому меняем ее на форму "изготовленных".

Comment: менять на форму "изготовленных" нежелательно, с сущ. жен.рода употребляется им./вин. падеж прилагательного/причастия, а не родительный.

Comment: Эта форма  употребляется в сочетании "три изготовленные мачты", чтобы обеспечить согласование во мн. числе. В нашем же случае стоит более трудная задача - убрать сочетание  "будет - изготовленные", которое плохо воспринимается на слух. Поэтому вполне допустимо отступление от этого формального правила.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. На яхте **будет** три мачты, изготовленные из углеродного волокна.

По-моему, коряво (в сочетании с *изготовленн**ые***). Можно исправить, выкинув причастие:

***На яхте будет три мачты из углеродного волокна.***

==========

> 2. На яхте будут три мачты, изготовленные из углеродного волокна.

Такой вариант моё ухо не режет. Корректировать бы не стал.